# TSQL Function to find a county based on city and zip

Tags: t-sql, user-defined-functions, zipcode

I have a table that has city, state, zip, county and a createdate. I need to have a function that gives me the county name based on the city and zip input where the createdate less than 1/1/2012. What I started with is this:

```
    ALTER FUNCTION dbo.fn_GetDefaultCounty (
@zip INT,
@city VARCHAR(25)
)
    RETURNS VARCHAR(25)
    AS
    BEGIN

DECLARE @county VARCHAR(25)

SELECT @county = county
FROM tzprod.plandata_rpt.dbo.zipcode
WHERE createdate < '1/1/2012'

RETURN @county
    END
```

But it's not working. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't include the input (ZIP, City).

```
SELECT @county = county
FROM tzprod.plandata_rpt.dbo.zipcode
WHERE zip = @zip AND 
    city = @city AND
    createdate < '1/1/2012'
```